# Understanding the notation $H:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ for bilinear forms

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, definition, bilinear-form

I would like to  present here definition of Bilinear forms

[image]

Here I would like to understand  notation

Let $H:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$

Does notation $V\times V$ mean  Power set of  Vector space?i mean Cartesian product? because  Cartesian product  is defined as
[image]

For instance  like this
[image]

in other words,  is Bilinear form linear map from  Power set of vector space to some field $F$ ?thanks in  advance

Comment: It is *always* cartesian product...unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $H:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ means that $H$ is a map from the vector space $V \times V$ to the vector space $\Bbb F$.

You're asking: what is $V \times V$ ?
As a set, it is the cartesian product of $V$ with itself:
$$V \times V = \{(v,w) \mid v,w \in V\}$$

It is moreover $\Bbb F$-vector space with the following *componentwise* operations:
$$(v,w) \oplus (v',w') := (v+v',w+w') \qquad
\lambda \odot(v,w):=(\lambda \cdot v,\lambda\cdot w)$$
for any $\lambda \in \Bbb F,v,w\in V$.

Comment: thanks very much ,last one mean  tensor product right

Comment: @dato : oh no, this is just a specific notation for $+$ and $\cdot$ I used for $V \times V$ (to make them different from the $+$ and $\cdot$ of $V$). Is that clear for you?

Comment: ok ok,  i see,i had  the question   when someone says  tensor product or tensor  sum, are they meaning  kronecker product  and kronecker sum?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: @datodatuashvili: The Kronecker product is an operation on two matrices, while the tensor product is an operation on two vector spaces. Both are denoted by $\otimes$, but they don't act on the same objects. I've never seen the notion of "tensor sum".

Comment: @datodatuashvili: for me, the tensor product is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). It is related to Kronecker products, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps).

Comment: like a outer product  , similar  almost

Comment: @datodatuashvili : yes, in some sense. It obviously depends on what you mean by "outer product".